# command link not working in child nodes of PrimeFaces tree

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to use commandLink inside primefaces basic tree the commandLink is working fine in main nodes while does nothing in child nodes.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


    <h:form>
        <p:commandLink value="Add Component"  action="#{subComponentManagedBean.addSubComponentFormNavigation()}" />

        <br><h:outputText value="Componet Tree Demonstration" style="color: blue;font-weight: bold;padding-bottom: 10px;text-align: center;"/>

        <p:tree value="#{subComponentManagedBean.componentTree}" var="node"  id="treeSingle" style="border:none;width: 100%;" >
            <p:treeNode   >
                <h:outputText value="#{node.componentName}" /> <p:spacer width="100" height="0" />    
                <p:commandLink id="tot#{node.componentId}" ajax="false"  value="Add"  action="#{subComponentManagedBean.addChildComponent(node)}"  /><p:spacer width="100" height="0"/>                        
            </p:treeNode>
        </p:tree>         
    </h:form>               

</html>
```

Comment: Will someone just tell me wheater a commandLinks works in root nodes of <p:tree> or not...?

Comment: I have just noticed that the link on child node works fine if the data in tree is loaded from constuctor and no other way...